# Virtual column in selection, which in turn fills this column with another selection in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to create selection with a virtual column and in turn this column is filled with another selection?

Is it possible?

Example:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.nom, amount 
FROM 
    person

amount = SUM(SELECT ar.amount FROM amount_r ar WHERE ar.id_person = p.id)
```

Comment: @cte6, use this `SUM(isnull(ar.amount, 0)) as amount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT  p.id,
        p.nom, 
        ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ar.amount)
                FROM amount_r ar 
                WHERE ar.id_person = p.id
                ),0)
FROM person as p
```

But, and this would be the best way, you could use group by:

```
SELECT  p.id,
        p.nom, 
        SUM(IIF(ar.amount IS NULL,0,ar.amount)) as amount
FROM person as p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN amount_r as ar ON ar.id_person = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.nom
```

Comment: Is there any way to change data that is null to zero?

Comment: I have modified both versions so now if they don't find records in the amount_r table they return a zero.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a correlated subquery?

```
SELECT p.id, p.nom,
       SUM(SELECT ar.amount FROM amount_r ar WHERE ar.id_person =p.id) as amount
FROM person p;
```

Comment: @LuisChavarria . . . What "mistakes"?  Your comment is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query, you can add additional columns as many as you want. Its important that you are able to `join` your `sum(amount)`

```
select p.id, p.nom, t1.amount
from person p
left join (
   select p.id, sum(isnull(ar.amount, 0)) as amount
   from person p
   inner join amount ar on ar.id_person = p.id
   group by p.id
) as t1 on t1.id = p.id
```